# Remote Control event in iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera, headphones

Trying to figure out how to read the Apple headphone's volume buttons to use as a trigger for the camera shutter (as the Apple Camera app does).

From the documentation on [Remote Control Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html), 
[Remote Control Received With Event](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:), and [this git repo](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch14p643ducking/ch27p912ducking/Player.swift), I've pieced together that I'll probably need an `AVAudioPlayer` object, `.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()`, and `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent`, along with making this view `canBecomeFirstResponder()` `return true`.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    var player: AVAudioPlayer!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var session: AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        session.setActive(true, error: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        println("viewDidAppear worked...")
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    }

    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent) {
        let rc = event.subtype
        println("does this work? \(rc.rawValue)")
        //takePicture()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

I expected to get `"does this work"` when hitting the volume buttons on the headphones, instead I just see it adjust the headphone volume like normal. So I must be missing something, maybe with a `delegate` or `AVSession`?

Answer (score 8):

I cross-posted this on [r/swift](http://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/37npx2/accessing_headset_controls/), where I was told it probably requires playing audio (quoted straight from the documentation).

So while this isn't the ideal solution, it works for my own private use.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    var testPlayer: AVAudioPlayer? = nil

    func loadSound(filename: NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename as String, withExtension: "caf")
        var error: NSError? = nil
        let player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
        if error != nil {
            println("Error loading \(url): \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            player.prepareToPlay()
        }
        return player
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.testPlayer = self.loadSound("silence")
        self.testPlayer?.numberOfLoops = -1
        self.testPlayer?.play()
    }

    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    }

    override func remoteControlReceivedWithEvent(event: UIEvent) {
        let rc = event.subtype
        println("rc.rawValue: \(rc.rawValue)")
        // take photo
    }
}
```

I noticed that in Apple's camera app, the +/- volume buttons trigger the camera, and the microphone button pauses/plays any audio running in another app, but in this implementation the volume buttons still control the volume (and any audio has been paused when the app is launched).

An `rc.rawValue: 103` corresponds to a single click of the microphone button, a double click returns `104`, and a triple click returns `105`, and then sometimes bumping a couple at a time returns a `108` or `109`.

Comment: This works for me (with slight modification for Swift 3) privately. Does anyone know if usage like this will be accepted for the App store?

Answer (score 3):

Based on Cody's answer but updated for 2019 (Swift 5)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    var myPlayer: AVAudioPlayer? = nil

    func loadSound(filename: NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer? {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename as String, withExtension: "mp3")
        do {
            let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url ?? URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
            player.prepareToPlay()
            return player
        }
        catch {
            print("Error : \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let testPlayer = loadSound(filename: "silence") else {
            print("Not able to load the sound")
            return
        }
        testPlayer.delegate = self
        testPlayer.volume = 0.8
        testPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        myPlayer = testPlayer
        myPlayer?.play()
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
    }

    override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
        let rc = event?.subtype
        print("rc.rawValue: \(rc?.rawValue)")
        // Do your thing
    }
}
```